# HttpResponseException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am facing a big problem for handling errors in MVC 4 webAPI. Here I want to validate  incoming request and send back a BadRequest response.

For that i am using the code

```
public Product GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product item = repository.Get(id);
   if (item == null)
   {
     throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
   }
   return item;
}
```

But In case of null id, VS2010 will produce another error like

"Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details".

How can i resolve this problem

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Which URL you used to call action GetProduct?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is actually correct. What you are seeing is Visual Studio's insistence on catching unhandled exceptions (unhandled within your app that is).

`HttpResponseException` exceptions are handled by the routing that called your Web API and your code will simply generate a 404 error.

Once you install your code on a Web server, it will simply return a 404 error if no matching record exists.

*While the suggestion on using a constraint is useful for basic checks, the real use of the 404 is to report that a specific request entry did not exist in the database (rather than did not exist in the URL).*

Comment: I have used similar code to throw an HttpResponseException but I am still getting a yellow screen of death (on a live server) with "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception..." Do you know how I can bypass this unhelpful message? Thanks

Comment: @Andy: turn on the debug option in your web.config (in system.web section) so that the error details are not masked (that is a security precaution so that your code is not exposed).

Answer (score 2):

Use a route constraint to disable `null` ids: `@"\d+"`. This way the controller action won't even resolve if you don't pass a numeric id in the url and the routing engine will directly return 404.

Comment: The purpose of `HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound))` is to throw an exception to produce a 404 error *if there is no matching record* for a REST request. Constraints only validate the type of value, not whether a matching record exists for that value. I have add an answer to cover this.

Answer (score 1):

I would just change the parameter to int? and then do a HasValue check and throw the desired exception. Like this (assuming you want to throw the same exception):

```
public Product GetProduct(int? id)
{
    Product item;
    if (id.HasValue){
        item = repository.Get(id);
    }
    if (item == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }
    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in, http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling, uncaught/unuser-handled exceptions are translated by default into HTTP responses. Throwing HttpResponseException allows you to specify much of this HTTP response (such as the 404 Not Found status code).

As TrueBlueAussie mentioned, Visual Studio will still break on these exceptions. To disable this:

1. From the menu, go to DEBUG -> Exceptions...
2. In the Exceptions dialog, add "System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException" to the Common Language Runtime Exceptions tree.
3. Uncheck the new System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException's User-unhandled box.